# hover over listbox option - not working with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I want to catch an event whenever a user hovers over a list element.

The following code below works fine with Mozilla and Chrome but not in IE8. How can I get it to work in IE8?

Here's the jsFiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/tromanow/U9wAz/

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thelist option').hover(function(e){
       alert('here');
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="thelist" name="sometext" size="4" >
    <option data-info="this is text1">text1</option>
    <option data-info="this is text2">text2</option>
    <option data-info="this is text3">text3</option>
    <option data-info="this is text4">text4</option>
    <option data-info="this is text5">text5</option>
    <option data-info="this is text5">text6</option>
    <option data-info="this is text5">text7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: IE8 does not support ``pageX``, you should use jQuery's built in ``pageOffset`` property, or handle IE8 using clientX/ClientY more in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226479/why-in-firefox-it-is-ok-but-in-ie8-it-print-undefined-undefined) SO post.

Comment: I removed references to pageX. Alert box still won't even come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that in Internet Explorer (even in recent versions such as IE9/IE10 sadly), `Hover`/`Mouseover` events **will not fire** when the object in question is an `<option>`.

See the list of available `<option>` events for the IE browsers [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Does the IE documentation link apply to IE8 or higher? I tried a few events listed in the documentation and most of them error out as unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

what if you use:

```
$('#thelist').hover(function(e){
  alert(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
});
```

Comment: Nope. This will only trigger when you mouse into the whole box. It won't trigger when you hover over another element once in the box.